# Two methods for the same route (one with parameters, the other without) with FOSRestBundle

Tags: php, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm trying to have the same route for two different functions with FOSRestBundle and Symfony. Here is what I have:

```
    /**
    * @Rest\Get("/users")
    * @QueryParam(name="login")
    */
    public function getLoginAvailability(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher)
    {
        return $this->_checkLoginAvailability($paramFetcher->get('login'));
    }

    /**
    * @Rest\Get("/users")
    */
    public function otherFunc()
    {
        return "other";
    }
```

The problem is: when I call the first function via an HTTP GET Request (giving it a login param), it is executing the second one, and ignores the first function. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Why not handling it in one route by checking whether your param has been set and depending on the result returning what you wish?

```
/**
* @Rest\Get("/users")
* @QueryParam(name="login")
*/
public function getLoginAvailability(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher)
{

  $params = $paramFetcher->all();

  if (array_key_exists('login', $params)) {
    return $this->_checkLoginAvailability($params['login']);
  } else {
    return $this->otherFunc();
}

private function otherFunc()
{
    return "other";
}
```